# Reading .csv file using fgets() function

Tags: c

I have a .csv file which contains 4 rows and 2 columns of data as displayed below:

```
0;0
0;1
1;0
1;1
```

My goal is to read the data and store it into a multidimensional array define as trIn[4][2]. The problem is that whenever I run the programme and print the value stored, the values stored in row 1 (or row 0) are wrong and seem random. Here is the code I wrote, I would much appreciate it if anyone could help.

```
FILE *inptr;
inptr = fopen("in.csv", "r");
if(inptr == NULL)
{
    printf("ERROR: Could not open file 'in.csv'\n");
    return 1;
}

// store the values from .csv file to mutl-dim arrays
char content[100];
int i;
for(i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    fgets(content, 100, inptr);
    trIn[i][0] = content[0] - '0';
    trIn[i][1] = content[2] - '0';

    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        printf("trIn[%d][0] = %d\ntrIn[%d][1] = %d\n", i, trIn[i][0], i, trIn[i][1]);
    }
}
return 0;
```

What gets displayed on my terminal is the following

```
trIn[0][0] = -65
trIn[0][1] = -113
trIn[1][0] = 0
trIn[1][1] = 1
trIn[2][0] = 1
trIn[2][1] = 0
trIn[3][0] = 1
trIn[3][1] = 1
```

Comment: The posting is labeled c# but has only c.  The issue is due to some files contaning a header row or there is different return characters in some of the files.

Comment: Just after `fgets` add: `printf("%zu %s\n", strlen(content), content);` How does the output look now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data file starts with a BOM — Byte Order Mark — probably because it is on (or from) Windows and contains UTF-8 data.

See the Unicode FAQ on [BOM — Byte Order Mark](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom1). The bytes in the BOM would be 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF.

This little program shows that when you subtract `'0'` from the bytes of the BOM, you get the values you see in your output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char bom[] = "\xEF\xBB\xBF";

    for (int i = 0; bom[i] != '\0'; i++)
        printf("%d: 0x%.2X => %d\n", i, (unsigned char)bom[i], bom[i] - '0');
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
0: 0xEF => -65
1: 0xBB => -117
2: 0xBF => -113
```

As you can see, the mapped values at index 0 and 2 are -65 and -113, exactly as you found.

You can skip the BOM by code such as:

```
char *data = content;
if (strncmp(data, "\xEF\xBB\xBF", 3) == 0)
    data += 3;   /* Skip BOM */
```

You then analyze `data[0]` and `data[2]`.  Your scanning algorithm is very fragile, but the BOM just makes it harder.  It can be a problem with files generated on Windows.  Unix systems usually do not put a BOM at the start of UTF-8 data files.